# Задача "Стильная одежда" Python

Tags: python

Глеб обожает шоппинг. Как-то раз он загорелся идеей подобрать себе майку и штаны так, чтобы выглядеть в них максимально стильно. В понимании Глеба стильность одежды тем больше, чем меньше разница в цвете элементов его одежды.

В наличии имеется N (1 ≤ N ≤ 100 000) маек и M (1 ≤ M ≤ 100 000) штанов, про каждый элемент известен его цвет (целое число от 1 до 10 000 000). Помогите Глебу выбрать одну майку и одни штаны так, чтобы разница в их цвете была как можно меньше.

**Входные данные**

Сначала вводится информация о майках: в первой строке целое число N (1 ≤ N ≤ 100 000) и во второй N целых чисел от 1 до 10 000 000 — цвета имеющихся в наличии маек. Гарантируется, что номера цветов идут в возрастающем порядке (в частности, цвета никаких двух маек не совпадают).

Далее в том же формате идёт описание штанов: их количество M (1 ≤ M ≤ 100 000) и в следующей строке M целых чисел от 1 до 10 000 000 в возрастающем порядке — цвета штанов.

**Выходные данные**

Выведите пару неотрицательных чисел — цвет майки и цвет штанов, которые следует выбрать Глебу. Если вариантов выбора несколько, выведите любой из них.

```
n = int(input())

maika = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

m = int(input())
shtani = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

minem = None

j = 0
i = 0
save_i = i
save_j = j

while i < len(maika) and j < len(shtani):
    now = abs(maika[i] - shtani[j])
    if minem is None or minem > now:
        save_i = i
        save_j = j
        j += 1
        minem = now
    else:
        j = save_j + 1
        i += 1

while i < len(maika):
    now = abs(maika[i] - shtani[j - 1])
    if minem > now:
        save_i = i
        save_j = j - 1
    i += 1

while j < len(shtani):
    now = abs(maika[i - 1] - shtani[j])
    if minem > now:
        save_j = j
        save_i = i - 1
    j += 1

print(maika[save_i], shtani[save_j])
```

6 тестов прошло, на 7м валится. И не знаю, в чем проблема может быть (эх почему бы не выкладывать эти проклятые тесты в открытый доступ)

Comment: У вас не принят ни один ответ на ваши вопросы. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer. Почему i и j в первом цикле обрабатываются по-разному?

Comment: Зачем делать len(maika) и len(Shtany), если эти числа сразу даны явно? Зачем лишний раз проверять на None, если можно сразу установить на максимальное значение, которое тоже явно указано в задаче? Что происходит в первом цикле?